# Converting an Array[Double] Column into a string or two different columns with Spark Dataframe Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I hit a snag earlier, trying to do some transformations within Spark Dataframes.

Let's say I have  a dataframe of schema :

```
root
|-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
|-- userid: string (nullable = true)
|-- pubuid: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to get rid of the array(double) in coordinates, and instead get a DF with row that look like

```
"coordinates(0),coordinates(1)", userid, pubuid 
                   or something like 
 coordinates(0), coordinates(1), userid, pubuid .
```

With Scala I could do

```
coordinates.mkString(",")
```

but in DataFrames coordinates resolves to a java.util.List.

So far I worked around the issue, by reading into an RDD, transforming then building a new DF. But I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do that with Dataframes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an UDF:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, lit}

val mkString = udf((a: Seq[Double]) => a.mkString(", "))
df.withColumn("coordinates_string", mkString($"coordinates"))
```

or

```scala
val apply = udf((a: Seq[Double], i: Int) => a(i))
df.select(
  $"*", 
  apply($"coordinates", lit(0)).alias("x"),
  apply($"coordinates", lit(1)).alias("y")
)
```

**Edit**:

In the recent versions you can also use `concat_ws`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws

df.withColumn(
  "coordinates_string", concat_ws(",", $"coordinates")
)
```

or simple `Column.apply`:

```scala
df.select($"*", $"coordinates"(0).alias("x"), $"coordinates"(1).alias("y"))
```