# array group by iteration in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have a array with data like this.

```
tagid,timestamp,listner,orgid,suborgid,rssi
[4,1496745915,718,4,3,0.30]
[2,1496745915,3878,4,3,0.20]
[4,1496745918,362,4,3,0.60]
[4,1496745913,362,4,3,0.60]
```

I want to iterate this array and find the latest 10 seconds timestamp data for each tag & listner.This is my code.

```
 override def inputSchema: StructType =
 StructType(StructField("time", StringType) :: StructField("tagid", StringType) :: StructField("listener", StringType) :: StructField("rssi", StringType) :: Nil)

   override def initialize(buffer: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
buffer(0) = Array[String]();
}

override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit =      {
buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0) :+ (input.getAs[String](0)+";"+
  input.getAs[String](1)+";"+input.getAs[String](2));
}

override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit     =  {
buffer1(0) = buffer1.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0) ++ buffer2.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0)
}

override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
val in_array = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0);
}
```

The in_array contains all the data.I dont know how to proceed further .Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to use `udaf` and for a beginner its a nightmare. By the way `udaf` will return you one row for each group and to get all the original `rows` from aggregated `dataframe` would be another nightmare.

I am assuming that you have a text file with data as

```
tagid,timestamp,listner,orgid,suborgid,rssi
4,1496745915,718,4,3,0.30
2,1496745915,3878,4,3,0.20
4,1496745918,362,4,3,0.60
4,1496745913,362,4,3,0.60
```

If yes than reading the file to dataframe is quite easy as

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", true).load("path to the above file")
df.show(false)
```

This should give you dataframe as

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
|tagid|timestamp |listner|orgid|suborgid|rssi|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
|4    |1496745915|718    |4    |3       |0.30|
|2    |1496745915|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|
|4    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.60|
|4    |1496745913|362    |4    |3       |0.60|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+
```

Now you are looking to filter in only the data that are within 10 seconds of latest timestamp for each tagid and listner. For this use following code

```
val windowSpec = Window
                    .orderBy($"timestamp".desc)  //latest to come first
                    .partitionBy("tagid", "listner")//grouping data
```

You will have to put latest timestamp in each row for each groups created above so that you can find the time difference. For that do following

```
df.withColumn("firstValue", first("timestamp") over windowSpec)
```

This will create a new column as

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+----------+
|tagid|timestamp |listner|orgid|suborgid|rssi|firstValue|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+----------+
|2    |1496745915|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|1496745915|
|4    |1496745915|718    |4    |3       |0.30|1496745915|
|4    |1496745918|362    |4    |3       |0.60|1496745918|
|4    |1496745913|362    |4    |3       |0.60|1496745918|
+-----+----------+-------+-----+--------+----+----------+
```

Next step would be simple just to check if the time difference is less than 10 or not and filter it

```
df.filter($"firstValue".cast("long")-$"timestamp".cast("long") < 10)
```

Finally time to remove unwanted columns

```
df.drop("firstValue")
```

I hope the answer is clear and understanding

Its more clear if you convert the timestamp to real timestamp as

```
+-----+-------------------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+---------+
|tagid|timestamp          |listner|orgid|suborgid|rssi|firstValue         |differnce|
+-----+-------------------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+---------+
|2    |2017-06-06 16:30:15|3878   |4    |3       |0.20|2017-06-06 16:30:15|0        |
|4    |2017-06-06 16:30:15|718    |4    |3       |0.30|2017-06-06 16:30:15|0        |
|4    |2017-06-06 16:30:18|362    |4    |3       |0.60|2017-06-06 16:30:18|0        |
|4    |2017-06-06 16:30:13|362    |4    |3       |0.60|2017-06-06 16:30:18|5        |
+-----+-------------------+-------+-----+--------+----+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Yeah that question also asked my me only. I have a doubt what is window in the above code.It throws error for me.Any import is needed ?

Comment: you need to import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

Answer (score 0):

First you are not iterating over an array. Your "array" is actually a schema and you should define your dataframe to be this way (i.e. each element should be a column). If your dataframe has arrays of string you can create the columns by using a udf (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166260/converting-an-arraydouble-column-into-a-string-or-two-different-columns-with-s)

Next you should convert your timestamp to a timestamp type so it would be orderable.

Lastly you could do argmax (see [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1023043053387187/3170497669323442/2840265927289860/latest.html)) for each of the two column

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your array

```
val arr = Array((4,1499340495,718,4,3,0.30),
                (2,1496745915,3878,4,3,0.20),
                (4,1499340495,362,4,3,0.60),
                (4,1496745913,362,4,3,0.60))
```

`java.time.Instant` is available in Java 8

```
import java.time.instant

arr.filter( x => (Instant.now.getEpochSecond - x._2) <= 10 )
```